# Is there an object-oriented language that allows low-level access to objects?

Tags: oop, programming-languages

A language I am looking for in this question should have the following characteristics:

- compile to machine code,
- have C++-style OOP design (possibly restricted to single-class inheritance),
- ideally be from the C family (not a requirement),
- allow handling unitialized stack-allocated objects,
- *allow direct calling of constructors and destructors as functions,* including control over how, when and whether at all a superclass constructor/destructor is called,
- *allow direct read/write access to the virtual table and RTTI data,*
- ideally *not distinguish between static and non-static member functions* (the latter would just overtly accept one more parameter for `this`),
- optionally: allow flow control during exceptions (e.g., calling destructors and forwarding stack unwinding).

The three points in italics happen in C++ behind the scenes and trying to interfere with them causes undefined behaviour, despite the fact that in common implementations they are very straightforward. Some others are against its principles. That is for good reasons, of course, but all in all it is just a design choice. Why I'm interested in a language which doesn't obscure them by design:

- one could create subclasses on the fly, Java-anonymous-class style (e.g., create an instance of a base class but replace some virtual function with own function pointer without needing to define a new class),
- one could design own faster but semantically equivalent versions of, e.g., dynamic type casts, taking into account contracts or assumptions the compiler can't know,
- one could give their classes (those allowing RTTI) human-readable names available at run time using existing mechanisms,
- one could store additional "polymorphic" data with the object, like virtual non-function members,
- students could more directly understand the inner workings of inheritance, type identification, etc.

Of course, one can just stay with C, but my point is that the language *would* actually be object-oriented and would by default do all the "magic" correctly for the user unless the additional flexibility would actually be required. It would be the user's responsibility to deal with situations they caused by not playing nice.

Does any such language (possibly obscure) exist? If not, what are the closest matches and which conditions they satisfy?

Comment: You *are* familiar with placement new, yes?

Comment: You could just do the italic things in C++ manually.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Sure, but that only goes part of the way. E.g. it won't let you leave the object uninitialized.

Comment: @nwp You can't without invoking UB. The standard does not even define an existence of a vtable.

Comment: By far the closest match is C++. Next closest is probably D.

Comment: @ close voters: How is this off topic? Which of the negative points [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) does it fall under? I believe on the contrary this is a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers" **as well as** "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: (It's presumably answerable by people who know more languages than me. For example I do not know Forth. The answer can also be negative, as in the comment above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern languages deliberately avoid giving the programmer too much low level power, since that tends to create expensive and difficult to maintain code.

That being said, although I don't know of any languages that match precisely what you are looking for, the closest I can think of is an old but very powerful language called Forth. Although it's original design didn't include object oriented structures, expansions to the language have been made to support this. Unlike most languages, Forth has no problem giving the programmer assembly-language level power freely mixed in with high level development concepts, such as functional programming and object oriented inheritance. However, it is very different than the C family of languages, so unless you are already familiar with it, it will take some study before you'd be able to use it effectively.

Forth is such a powerful language that you can literally design your own object oriented mechanisms in the language itself, engineering whatever inheritance, encapsulation, or any other object oriented principle you'd like to have. You can also make it as automatic, or manual as you want, for example, selecting whether super class constructors are automatically called or not.

This probably doesn't help you too much though since you are probably looking for more of a C like language. The only other thing I can think of is a high level assembly language, maybe a nasm-like language with a lot of syntatic sugar built into the preprocessor.

Comment: That sounds amazing! The C-family was just a soft requirement, I don't have a problem with that.

Comment: Well, a language strong enough that one can **implement** OOP in it (and then use the abstraction right away) seems to be a clear winner! I'll need to do some reading on Gforth but I don't see any more answers coming at this point. What I read on Forth itself in convincing.